# How can I override the sort variable?

Tags: views, 8

For my view in Drupal 8 I have added a sorting criteria based on the custom field. Now, when I sort the content in the url one can see a sorting value as a name of that field.

Like ?sort_by=field_custom_value

How can I override the value of the sort criteria, so that the path doesn't look so ugly.

Expected: ?sort_by=something_different

Answer (score 1):

This module might help [Query Parameters To URL](https://www.drupal.org/project/query_parameters_to_url).

There's a D8 sandbox: [Drupal 8 port](https://www.drupal.org/project/query_parameters_to_url/issues/2995815)

The module seems very useful, maybe it would get more attention if more people used it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the machine name of the custom field. If you haven't used the field for much yet, that is a quick solution.

If you already have a lot of nodes with data in that field, create a new field with a nicer machine name and copy the data from the old field to the new field. There are a variety of ways to do this, but you might want to try Views Bulk Operations or Feeds Tamper.

Comment: You can change the name of it in the filter config I believe.

Comment: Not for sorting criteria unfortunately